# How to handle Keyboard Shortcut in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am trying to add a keyboard shortcut for use with an external Bluetooth Keyboard to a `UIViewController` with no `UITextField` or `UITextView` on it. So far I tried the following with no success

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[
             [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"e" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(handleShortcut:)]];
}

- (void)handleShortcut:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
}
```

I also stumbled over [this post](http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/75914438806/supporting-keyboard-shortcuts-without-uitextview) with a workaround but it didn't work for me. Any ideas how to handle shortcuts in a UIViewController with not textfields on it?

Comment: Are you using an external keyboard with your iOS device?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is for using an external Bluetooth Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of UIView. Add methods to it:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray<UIKeyCommand *>*)keyCommands {
    return @[
//example shortcut CTRL+Cmnd+1
             [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"1" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand | UIKeyModifierControl action:@selector(pressed:)]
];
        }
```

Add needed selector in ("pressed:" in my case)

Set your ViewController view class - your subclass.

Result - "2015-11-30 17:34:28.815 ProjectName[5204:2899520] 1"

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. It doesn't work on the UIViewController to "activate" the keyCommands. The `becomeFirstResponder` only had an effect with a UITextView/Field.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly old question but since Google has this link high when searching for keyboard shortcuts for a `UIViewController`, here's the current (Nov 2017) answer:

`UIViewController` now has a simple method called `-addKeyCommand:` so just add your command(s) to your view controller using this method and you are good to go.